# How to make SeekBar value go up by 5s? And how to pass user selected seekbar value to a method?

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have two problems, first, I want my seekbar to display values as follows: 5, 10, 15, 20...30. I have set max=30 and progress=5, but that doesn't do. Second, I need the value selected by the user via seekbar to be passed into calculatePayments() method after the user clicks the Calculate button. Anyone please help me out? I would appreciate it! Thanks!

public class AKMainActivity extends Activity {

```
private EditText loanAmount, interestRate, loanYears; 
private TextView monthlyPaymentsResult, totalPaymentsResult, seek_barTV; 
private static SeekBar seek_bar;
private static TextView textview_seek;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_akmain);

    seekbarr();
    loanAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loanET);
    interestRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.intrateET);
    monthlyPaymentsResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthlyResultTV);
    totalPaymentsResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalResultsTV);

}

public void seekbarr(){

    seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    textview_seek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekbarTV);
    textview_seek.setText(seek_bar.getProgress() + "Years");

    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int years_number = 5;

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            textview_seek.setText(years_number + " Years");

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            years_number = progress;
            textview_seek.setText(years_number + " Years");
            progress = seek_bar.getProgress();


        }
    });

}


public void calculatePayments(View clickedButton) {

    double loan = Integer.parseInt(loanAmount.getText().toString());
    double interest = (Integer.parseInt(interestRate.getText().toString()));

    double years = seek_bar.getProgress();

    double r = years / 1200;
    double r1 = Math.pow(r + 1, years);

    double monthlyPayment = (double) ((r + (r / (r1 - 1))) * loan);
    double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * years;

    monthlyPaymentsResult.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment));
    totalPaymentsResult.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totalPayment));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To set the progress increment you can do:

```
seekBar.incrementProgressBy(5);
```

You also need to get a reference to your button, the same way you did for you other views (TextView, SeekBar,etc.) and in your Button's onClick listener you can call the calculatePayments method, with the current seekbar value as an argument. To get the current value of the seekbar use:

```
seekBar.getProgress();
```